# EMR cluster how to delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

How to delete or remove EMR cluster from AWS? I terminated a cluster but its still on the list on console.

Any help would be great. Does it matter if cluster is terminated and still showing up on list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A terminated cluster will appear on the list of some length of time.

The cluster *has* been terminated, as indicated by the status, and you will not be charged. However, it will still appear on the list for some time.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of EMR clusters, you can only terminate the cluster. Some documentation I have read suggests it will be completely deleted after 2 weeks. I don't think that is true since I still have terminated clusters from months ago. It's the same with Elastic Container Service clusters. You can try raising the issue with AWS support via email.